# resizing body when modal fade opens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im using Bootstrap. And on my page I have some modal.

`<div class="modal fade" id="SomeModalId" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalLabel" aria-hidden="false">...<div>`

And I have some elments which have it's width setted to the 100% body size. (For example, I have Bootstrap's nav bar which is 100% body width by default)

But when I open my modal, all the relative width's are getting smaller. It means that all elements with a constant width dont change, but all the element's with it's sizes setted for some % of the body are getting smaller (only their width, height doesnt change). For example, standard Bootstrap nav is getting smaller.

How can I fix it? I dont want to set constant width to all elemnts :(

Comment: please post relevant code.

Comment: @Harry , watch html here: https://github.com/equivalence1/hanabi/blob/master/hanabi/index.html